# How to install Thunderbird 10.0 after Thunderbird 11.0 is already installed?

Tags: installation, thunderbird

Thunderbird 11.0 is causing a lot of crashes and I'm [not alone in this experience](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116581/thunderbird-crashing-again-and-again#comment138085_116581). It was automatically recently updated though the Ubuntu Software Centre. I figure if I return to version 10, that will solve the problem.

How can I uninstall version 11 and go back to version 10 of Thunderbird without losing any settings or mail data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mail settings and your personal account information is in the ~/.thunderbird file. As long as you don't move that you will be okay.

Go to the synaptic package manager or use the ubuntu software center and remove the current thunderbird package. Then add the current mozilla ppa to the sources list

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-stable

sudo apt-get update
```

you then should be able to open synaptic and choose thunderbird 10.0.2 and install it.

If you have issues there you can always download from Mozilla Team [Here](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/thunderbird-stable/+build/3217802) just select your language and install the .deb file.

#### Caution! If you update, -  your *old* thunderbird will be upgraded.

you will also need to "pin" the app or freeze it from further updates by

```
echo <package> hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: Found this to work with Thunderbird 17 also