# How do I downgrade Thunderbird (or get a working version of Lightning)

Tags: thunderbird, downgrade, lightning

Could somebody please tell me how to roll Thunderbird back to 11.x, or get a working version of Lightning (which claims it is incompatible with 12.0).  I'm currently not able to view my calendar :(

Comment: I would have said, install the addon compatibility reporter addon, but it links to this page http://brian.kingsonline.net/talk/2012/02/compatible-by-default-and-the-add-ons-compatibility-reporter/ to say that it doesn't work any more. Bummer.

Comment: The latest stable release is TB 11; how did you get on TB 12? Are you using a PPA? Are you using 12.04? Did someone set up beta TB releases for you? Any information on how you got this version will go a long way towards getting you back to the stable version (assuming that's what you want).

Comment: Look at this here http://askubuntu.com/a/116620/46312 How to install Thunderbird 10.0 after Thunderbird 11.0 is already installed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Thunderbird 10.0 after Thunderbird 11.0 is already installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/116613/how-to-install-thunderbird-10-0-after-thunderbird-11-0-is-already-installed)

Answer (score 3):

You neednot downgrade thunderbird to get working version of Lightning. Install this addon

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning-nightly-updater-unof/?src=search

It will search for compatible version of Lightning and install it

Comment: There is no 64 bit support here so this will not work for most users.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with the in distro packages, you can use ppa-purge to remove the thunderbird-next PPA until compatible versions of lightning are available there.  This should roll you back to the distro version 11.

Answer (score 0):

You might see if the [Nightly Tester Tools addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/nightly-tester-tools/?src=search) can still disable addon compatibility checking. (The [Add-on Compatibility Reporter addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/), which I would have otherwise recommended instead, no longer disables compatibility checks.)